# Traefik Disable tls for only 1 container

Tags: tls1.3, bastion-host, traefik-routers

Good morning,
I am setting up a bastion container, here is my compose docker file:

```
traefik:
        restart: always
        image: traefik
        container_name: traefik
        hostname: traefik
        command:
          - --log.level=info
          - --api.insecure=true
          - --providers.docker
          - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
          - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
          - --entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443
          - --entryPoints.smtp.address=:25
          - --entryPoints.smtp-ssl.address=:465
          - --entryPoints.imap-ssl.address=:993
          - --entryPoints.sieve.address=:4190
          - --entryPoints.ssh-proxy.address=:8022
          - --metrics.prometheus=true
          - --metrics.prometheus.buckets=0.1,0.3,1.2,5.0
          - --providers.docker.watch
          - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true
          - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web
          - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=mail@mail
          - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/certs/acme.json
        ports:
          - 80:80
          - 443:443
          - 8080:8080
          - 25:25
          - 465:465
          - 993:993
          - 4190:4190
          - 8022:8022
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
          - /var/log/traefik:/var/log
          - ./traefik/certs:/certs
        networks:
          - backend
          - frontend
        labels:
          - traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-redirect-web-secure.redirectscheme.scheme=https
[...]
trasa_app:
        image: seknox/trasa:v1.1.4
        container_name: trasa_app
        restart: always
        labels:
          - traefik.enable=true
          - traefik.http.middlewares.bastion-redirect-web-secure.redirectscheme.scheme=https
          - traefik.http.routers.bastion-web.middlewares=bastion-redirect-web-secure
          - traefik.http.routers.bastion-web.rule=Host(`bastion.${DOMAINNAME}`)
          - traefik.http.routers.bastion-web.entrypoints=web
          - traefik.http.routers.bastion-web-secure.rule=Host(`bastion.${DOMAINNAME}`)
          #- traefik.http.routers.bastion-web-secure.tls.certresolver=myresolver
          - traefik.http.routers.bastion-web-secure.tls=false
          - traefik.http.routers.bastion-web-secure.entrypoints=web-secure
          - traefik.tcp.routers.ssh-proxy.rule=HostSNI(`*`)
          - traefik.tcp.routers.ssh-proxy.entrypoints=ssh-proxy
          - traefik.tcp.routers.ssh-proxy.service=ssh-proxy
          - traefik.tcp.services.ssh-proxy.loadbalancer.server.port=8022
        environment:
          - TRASA.LISTENADDR=bastion.${DOMAINNAME}
          - TRASA.AUTOCERT=true
          - DATABASE.SERVER=pgdb
          - REDIS.SERVER=redis:6379
          - PROXY.GUACDADDR=guacd:4822
        volumes:
          - /tmp/trasa/accessproxy/guac:/tmp/trasa/accessproxy/guac
        links:
          - pgdb:pgdb
          - redis:redis
          - guacd:guacd
        networks:
          - frontend
          - backend
```

Here is my problem:
When traefik manages the container certificate of trasa_app: I get an error "Error while setting TCP connection deadline: set tcp {ip}: use of closed network connection"

So what I want to do is disable obtaining the certificate from the trafik container so that the trasa_app container manages its own certificate.
so I added the label `traefik.http.routers.bastion-web-secure.tls=false` but when I access bastion.domainname: the certificate is "TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT"
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GVKi.png)

How can I do so that traefik does not manage the trasa certificate?

thank you very much in advance,

Dimox

When traefik manages the certificate, the trasa container does not have the key so there is an error...
When the trasa container manages the certificate, the traefik container returns a default certificate and not the trasa one...

Comment: I think what you need is TLS passthrough: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#passthrough

Answer (score 0):

You can define what Traefik will use as the default certificate by defining a TLSStore as seen [here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/tls/#default-certificate).